# Django-admin startproject mysite doesn't create directory

Tags: python, django

I use virtualenv and when I type "django-admin startproject mysite" then there are no errors but it also doesn't create directory, why?

Comment: is django installed inside the virtualenv

Comment: @ngawang13 yes it is

Answer (score 0):

use 'pwd' in terminal if you are a mac/linux user and 'cd' in your shell or command promp and so find your project in that directory but before that 'pip freeze' or 'pip list' it will give you a list of all the installed packages in your virtual environment make sure you have django in that list after that use dot after start project command
django-admin startproject mysite .